if-else unpredictable behaviour
I am trying to write a basic C program to display contents of a file on the screen.
I am facing a problem with the way if-else seems to work. Here are two codes which I think should work the same, but for some reason they do not.
Code 1:
    while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {    if(j==3&&c!=' ')
         {
            printf("%c",c);
            j++;
         }
    
         else if(j!=3)
         { 
            printf("%c",c);
            j++;
         }
    }
    

Code 2:
   while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
   {
       if(j==3&&c!=' ')
          printf("%c",c);
    
       else if(j!=3)
          printf("%c",c);
    
       j++;
   }

Please point out where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Re. "Here are two codes which I think should work the same": why?  They are quite obviously different.

They are not the same. What happens in each case if j == 3 && c == ‘ ‘?

@Paul Lynch, in case j==3 && c==' '  the while loop goes on and fgetc reads the next character into 'c' without printing anything and without incrementing 'j'.

@VinayakDeshmukh Not in both cases.

@Paul Lynch, you are right. I assumed that the if - else in my code covers all possible scenarios, which is obviously not right.

I suggest that you run your code line by line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, to understand why the behavior of both code snippets is different.

Let's consider negation of the expression j==3&&c!=' ' used in the if statement:
 if(j==3&&c!=' ')

That expression !(j==3&&c!=' ') is equivalent to j != 3 || c == ' '.
In the first code snippet the variable j is incremented only when j != 3
     else if(j!=3)
     { 
        printf("%c",c);
        j++;
     }

but is not incremented when c is equal to ' '.
In the second code snippet the variable j is incremented independent on whether c is equal to ' ' or not equal to ' '.

Because Code 1 doesn't increase j when j == 3 and c == ' ' but Code 2 does.
